# Why does adding adding ```flask_sockets.worker``` to gunicorn slow down gRPC client connection?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, grpc, grpc-python

I am building a flask server that connects to a background gRPC service. I planned to use gunicorn to serve the flask app. Adding a `flask_sockets.worker` is slowing it down terribly!

Here is a minimum working example,

```
import grpc                                                                                                                                                            
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = b"Hello, World!\n"

    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('{0}:{1}'.format('localhost', 40051))
    try:
        grpc.channel_ready_future(channel).result(timeout=1)
        data += b"\nChannel ready"
    except grpc.FutureTimeoutError:
        data += b"\nChannel not ready"
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

If I run the app using,

```
gunicorn -w 4 mwe:app -b :8000
```

everything seems to be fine. But if instead I use,

```
gunicorn -w 4 mwe:app -b :8000 -k flask_sockets.worker
```

the page takes forever to load. I need to use `flash_sockets` for some additional functionality. Eventually I see,

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:17489)
[WARNING] Worker graceful timeout (pid:17489)
```

and the page loads! How can I solve this issue?
My environment has,

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Sockets==0.2.1
gevent==1.4.0
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==0.4.15
grpcio==1.23.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
six==1.12.0
Werkzeug==0.15.5
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a shot in the dark, could you try to using a much more updated version of gevent?

> gevent==20.5.1

https://pypi.org/project/gevent/